# CDbException warning 1265 after updating matrix field

Tags: matrix, database, error-message

A testimonial matrix field has existed in our system for a couple of months. I've just deleted a block that's no longer needed, and am now receiving a SQL warning related to another one of the blocks. The warning occurs when I set the Max Length to anything lower than 145. Here's the warning text:

`` CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'field_testimonial_quotation' at row 1. The SQL statement executed was: ALTER TABLE `craft_matrixcontent_testimonialmatrix` CHANGE `field_testimonial_quotation` `field_testimonial_quotation` VARCHAR(110) NULL ``

I've checked all of the Entries that use this matrix block, and none of them are close to the Max Length limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column `field_testimonial_quotation` in your `craft_matrixcontent_testimonialmatrix` table has data in it that is longer than 145 characters long.

Since it looks like your MySQL box is running in strict mode, MySQL is warning you that data has been/will be truncated by changing the max length to something below that.

Comment: Right you are, @brad-bell. I checked all of the Entries that are available through the CMS front-end. But apparently there's leftover data from an old version of this Matrix block that is 145 characters long. This can only be seen directly in the database. I would open another question for this but I have no idea what led to it. Thanks for the help!